# Android App with SQL server

Tags: android, sql, database, web-services

I have a few questions regarding sql server in android.

Essentially, I am tring to create an app that communicates to a SQL server, runs queries, creates new tables, rows, etc. I have been doing a lot of research recently about getting a connection to a SQL server in android. I've seen the tutorial on using a php file and it seems that isn't quite what I am looking for.

My questions:

1. Is it possible to create an app like the one I described above?
2. Do I need to do it using a php file? (like the tutorials)
3. Is there another way to do what I am looking to do?
4. Should I create a webservice to do the database portion of it? If so, are there any tutorials out there about that?

I apologize for my noob-y questions. Thanks for your help

Comment: What type of server is it?
MySQL, MSSQL, Oracle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should definitely create a webservice, because otherwise any malicious user who has access to your app (downloads it) could easily trash your DB.  But allowing insertion and creation privileges to users seems like a bad idea already.

If your users need a *personal* db, why don't you use sqlite which is stored locally and has no access delays, and no internet connection requirements?  Why do you want a single db that is completely exposed to everyone?

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good idea to communicate directly to SQL server from Android Phones. You might hit  so many technical constraints when you keep going with the development. I am not sure about he end result as well. It would be great to go ahead with the service that way you might have lot of controls inside the application and design it efficiently... Just a thoughts :)